# paste0 in ifelse R

Tags: r, if-statement, datatable, paste

I try to use paste0 in an ifelse() to create a conditioned new variable in a data table. The code I use is the following:

```
data[, paste0("inc_2014_",i) := ifelse(paste0("testvar",i) == 2014, 1, 0)]
```

This does not work. There is no error message but the values of inc_2014_i (in my test case inc_2014_1) are all 0 whereas ther should be a couple of hundreds 1.

If I test

```
data[, paste0("inc_2014_",i) := ifelse(testvar1 == 2014, 1, 0)]
```

it works fine.

If I test

```
paste0("testvar",i)
```

I get the correct variable as output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does i come from?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @camille i comes from a loop. I have 8 variables testvart1, testva2, etc. For the sake of simplicity, I just defined i as 1 in the example.

Comment: You *haven't* defined it in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working, because you are trying to call the variable in the ifelse as a string.

Assuming i = 1, the result of `paste0("testvar",i)` is `"testvar1"` but ifelse needs `testvar1`, not as a string.

Use the function `get()` as follows and it should work.

```
data[, paste0("inc_2014_",i) := ifelse(get(paste0("testvar",i)) == 2014, 1, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through your columns to define i, maybe you can try:

```r
for(i in 1:length(grep("inc_2014_", colnames(data))))
{
    data[, paste0("inc_2014_",i) := ifelse(paste0("testvar",i) == 2014, 1, 0)]
}
```